# Conversion of string _id to mongoose ObjectId not giving expected results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm getting a mongodb document from another API in json format which has an _id attribute which i want to keep as a point of reference in another collection, so i want to store that same exact id which is supposed to be type `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` in my collection, so i naturally do type casting `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_id)` but that gives me an entire new objectId with a new hex value but i want that old exact same hex value.

Schema:

```js
const posts_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  caption: String,
  post_type: String,
  content: String,
  uuid: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  posted_datetime: Date,
  last_updated_datetime: Date,
})
```

The code where i get the json and convert the _id:

```js
axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: `http://localhost:3000/${req.body.username}`,
  responseType: 'json',
})
  .then((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.data);
    let newRecord = new postsModel({
      caption: req.body.caption,
      post_type: req.body.post_type,
      content: req.body.content,
      uuid: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(doc.data._id),
      posted_datetime: new Date(),
      last_updated_datetime: new Date(),
    });
    newRecord
      .save()
      .then((d) => {
        res.json(d);
        console.log('New post added!');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

So basically the error is `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(doc.data._id)` is giving me an entirely new ObjectId with a new Hex Value but i want an ObjectId with the same hex value which is in _id which is received from my other API.

Comment: Are you sure `doc.data._id` is defined?

Comment: it shows undefined when i show typeof(doc.data._id) @robertklep

Comment: but the value can be accessed. @robertklep

Comment: There's obviously something wrong there. The reason you're getting a new value is because Mongoose also thinks it's undefined.

Comment: @mukunddeepak can you post the result of console.log(doc.data) ?

Comment: yeah i figured out the error, doc.data is an array, i have to access the ids of the document inside it.